# dbupdateconcurrencyexception when deleting non existing items

Tags: entity-framework

i try to delete items from my database using EF 5, when items are present in db it works as expected, if the item to delete isn't on my DB i get the following exception :

"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries."

I create the object to delete from his ID as below :

```
var alert=new Alert{AlertID == alerteGuid};
unitOfWork.AlertRepository.Delete(alert);
unitOfWork.Save();
```

and my delete method :

```
 public void Delete(T entity)
 {
        if (context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbset.Attach(entity);
        }
        dbset.Remove(entity);

 }
```

thanks.